# undefined local variable or method `res' for main:Object (NameError)

Tags: ruby

I have the following little script that connects to a host, and gets some output.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'net/http'
require 'net/https'
require 'timeout'

serverurl = "http://www.google.com/"

uri = URI(serverurl)

res = Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, 'method' => 'login', 'username' => 'admin', 'password' => 'MySup3rDup3rp@55w0rd')

cookie = res['set-cookie']
if cookie.nil?
  puts "No cookie"
end
```

I want to use some timeout so I do:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'net/http'
require 'net/https'
require 'timeout'

serverurl = "http://www.google.com/"

uri = URI(serverurl)

begin
  timeout(10) do
    res = Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, 'method' => 'login', 'username' => 'admin', 'password' => 'MySup3rDup3rp@55w0rd')
  end
rescue StandardError,Timeout::Error
  puts "#{server} Timeout"
  exit(1)
end

cookie = res['set-cookie']
if cookie.nil?
  puts "No cookie"
end
```

Now I get some error:

```
test.rb:20:in `<main>': undefined local variable or method `res' for main:Object (NameError)
```

I don't know why, because a similar test code works without error:

```
require "timeout"

begin
  timeout(6) do
    sleep
  end
#rescue # under ruby >= 1.9 is ok
rescue StandardError,Timeout::Error # workaround for ruby < 1.9
  p "I'm sorry, Sir. We couldn't make it, Sir."
end
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is about **scope**. In Ruby, variables are only visible within the same scope where they are defined (exceptions are instance-, class-, and global variables as well as constants).

So in your example, `res` is only visible within the `timeout`-block. Add `res = nil` before the `begin`-block to make sure `res` is defined in the scope you actually need the value.

Comment: What if I declare it as global? @res

Comment: @bsteo: `@res` is not a global, it's an instance variable. But in the context of plain script, it doesn't make much difference

Comment: Just checked, `res = nil` or `@res` make my code work :)